# heroku: deploy react rails separate folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, reactjs, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku, but i can't find a way. I have in the root two folders, 'back' and 'front', the first is a rails api app and the second is a react app.

I think the react deploy is OK, but ruby is not. 
I have the buildpacks needed:
heroku/nodejs
heroku/tuby

Please help me out! :)

/package.json

```
{
  "name": "sophia",
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cd front && npm install && npm run build && cd ..",
    "deploy": "cp -a front/build/. back/public/",
    "postinstall": "npm run build && npm run deploy && echo 'Client built!'"
  }
}
```

Procfile

```
web: cd front && PORT=3000 npm start
api: cd back PORT=3001 && bundle exec rails s
```

/front/package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Heroku error

```
remote:          "homepage" :
remote:        
remote:        The build folder is ready to be deployed.
remote:        You may serve it with a static server:
remote:        
remote:          yarn global add serve
remote:          serve -s build
remote:        
remote:        Find out more about deployment here:
remote:        
remote:          
remote:        
remote:        
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:  !     Unmet dependencies don't fail npm install but may cause runtime issues
remote:        github.com/npm/npm/issues/7494
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Change to Node.js build process 
remote:        Heroku has begun executing the "build" script defined in package.json
remote:        during Node.js builds.
remote: 
remote:        Read more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1573
remote: 
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz
remote:        More info: devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to sophia-social-network.
remote: 
To git.heroku.com/sophia-social-network.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'hgit.heroku.com/sophia-social-network.git'
```

Comment: The `App not compatible with buildpack` error message is giving you a hint. Have you set the buildpacks needed for deploying your application? You might take a look to the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#officially-supported-buildpacks).

Comment: hi Sebastian! hahaha
yes.. i did check that.. i have this two:
heroku/nodejs
heroku/ruby

i added them with this command:
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs --index 1
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby --index 2

Comment: Which of both applications is throwing the buildpack incompatibility? Just checking, is that file really called "pachage.json"? not "package.json"?

Comment: About the first question, i think is the ruby app.. cause it says that the build is OK and it reads and compile my components, even found one or two warnings in them... about the second question, just a typo. Already edited.

Comment: Can you try clearing the buildpack and setting it again?

Comment: yes, i did it. even created a new app and added the builpacks before the deploy.. same error. :(

Comment: Do you really need to deploy them in the same package? From a maintenance perspective it seems like a much better idea to deploy each separately which also lets you scale the resources appropriately for the separate needs of the API / frontend.

Comment: maybe you are right.. do you know some tutorial to do just that? :) thanks!